# Test succeeding with mocha when it should fail

Tags: mocha.js

There are a few things I don't really get when I execute my mocha test scripts :

I am testing about 20 requests, and some of the tests are passing when they shouldn't. For example, I want to retrieve the countries in Europe, the result will be as following :

```
[ {name:'Germany',
   code:'de'},
  {name:'Spain',
   code:'es'},
...]


describe('get v2/continents/EU', function() {
  it('should return the country name', function(done) {
    options.path = "v2/continents/EU";
    http.get(options, function(res) {
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      var body = '';
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        expect(json.result[0].name).to.equal('France'); //This should fail
      });
      done();
    })
  })
})
```

The first country I retrieve in the list is Germany, not France, but the test still passes and I have no clue why, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you call to `done()` that is currently at the end of your test so that it is inside your handler for `res.on('end', ...)`: just after your `expect` call.

Currently, you tell Mocha that the test is ending before it actually ends, but in actually you want it to end only after you've gotten the results and tested them.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even pay attention, it was actually as you said finishing the test before comparing the expected results due to the asynchronous aspect